# How to check multi mapping for 2 lists?

Tags: python, algorithm, list

How do we check whether exists a valid mapping to let elements in each column are same?

such as

```
// upper case: Constant
// lower case: Variable 
// same variable name in different rows means different variable

1.
[x A x B]
[y y x x]
Impossible!
x in row1 mapping to y in row 2 which is mapped to A, meanwhile, x in row1 mapping to x in row2 which mapped to B

2.
[x A]
[B x]
Possible!
x in row1 mapping to B
x in row2 mapping to A

3.
[x A]
[y A]
Possible!
x in row1 mapping to y
x,y can be any constant
```

I hope the description of the question is clear enough.

This Logic problem confused me for a really long time

Thanks in advance for your answer!

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming problem to me, no?

Comment: Actually, It more close to the algorithm problem.

Comment: You might have better luck finding an answer on https://cs.stackexchange.com.